# How to have a parameter of an abstract data type?

Tags: c++, class, oop, abstract

I have an abstract class called **shape**.

```
class Shape{
public:
    virtual const ColorRGB getColor() const;
    virtual double rayIntersectionDistance(Ray r) = 0;
};
```

And now I've derived the following classes from **Shape**.

1. `class Sphere: public Shape { //implementation goes here }`
2. `class Plane: public Shape { //implementation goes here }`

I've implemented both **getColor()** and **rayIntersectionDistance(Ray r)** methods inside both classes, with additional methods specific to those classes.

So now, in another class, named **Scene**, I've a **render()** method, and it's prototype is:

```
void render(int width, int height, Shape s);
```

And this seems to be not working, the compiler is complaining me saying:

> error: cannot declare parameter 's' to be of abstract type 'Shape'

How can I make this happen? What would be a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing a `Shape` by value means passing an instance of `Shape`.  But `Shape` is abstract, so an instance cannot be created.

Pass a pointer or a reference instead.  `const` qualify if you do not intend the object passed to be modified (which will also prevent passing of objects that are declared `const`, as they should not be changed).

```
 void func(Shape &s);    // define these functions as required
 void func2(Shape *s);
 void func3(const Shape &s);

 int main()
 {
        Sphere s;   // assumed non-abstract

        const Sphere s2;

        func(s);     // will work
        func2(&s);    // ditto

        func3(s);   // okay
        func3(s2);  // okay

        func(s);   // rejected, as s2 is const
 }
```

Edit:

As mentioned by Barry in comments, it is also possible to pass smart pointers, such as `std::unique_pointer<Shape>` or `std::shared_pointer<Shape>` - and those can be passed by value.    That is unusual in practice, as mentioned by Richard Hodges, although it is possible.     In fact, any type which manages a pointer or reference to `Shape` can be passed - assuming its constructors (particularly the copy constructor) implements appropriate behaviour.

Comment: `func4(unique_ptr<Shape> )`, `func5(shared_ptr<Shape> )`, ... ;-)

Comment: @barry to be fair, passing a moved unique_ptr to a draw function would be unusual. @Peter I probably wouldn't encourage `func()` or `func2()`. way too abusable... `func3()` is the one.

Comment: @Barry - yes.   It is also possible to pass any type which contains a pointer or a reference to `Shape` - including smart pointer types like you mention - as long as that type manages its state appropriately.

Comment: @Richard - if the function needs to change state of the `Shape`, `const` is inappropriate.   Consider a `RotateAboutOrigin(Shape &)` which updates the coordinates of defining points (vertices, centre. etc) of the shape - even if that is done by calling non-`const` member functions of `Shape`.   That cannot accept a `const`.

Comment: @Peter you're right of course in the general case. I think I still had the ops question in mind when  commenting. The examples he gives are non-mutating functions.